# Setting up LAMP on Ubuntu 22.04: PHP info not displaying in browser

Tags: php, webserver, hosting, lamp

Why doesn't the PHP info webpage appear when testing PHP 8.1, installed during the LAMP setup on Ubuntu 22.04?

Could someone provide a command-line add-on with an explanation? Additionally, could you give details on PHP configuration, such as php.ini, and some common errors encountered during the LAMP stack setup with Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Change > to ?> please